# How to make javascript code compatible with node.js and the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Half of my javascript code does not run in node.js and the other half does not run in my browser (chrome).

The first half of the code runs an external "Hello World" .jar file and saves the string in the output variable. This code runs whitout problems in node.js. Nevertheless, when I try to paste the content of the output variable on an html (sencond half), I get an error. The browser does not recognize the require() sentence as well as node.js does not recognize the "document" object. I understand that Node.js is used to run javascript code frontend and backend, but I don't know what it has to be done to relate both worlds.

```
//first half
var jre = require('node-jre');
var output = 
jre.spawnSync(["E:/proyectosJavaScript/prueba1/HelloWorld.jar"], 
"hello.helloWorld", ["parametro"], { encoding: 'utf-8' })
.stdout.trim();
console.log(output);
//second half
var titulo = document.getElementById("P1t1");
titulo.innerHTML=`${output}`;



 //browser response:    
 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined at "nombreDelScript"

 //node.js response:
 ReferenceError: document is not defined
 at Object.<anonymous> (E:\proyectosJavaScript\prueba1\libreto.js:125:14)
 at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:688:30)
 at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:699:10)
 at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:598:32)
 at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:537:12)
 at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:529:3)
 at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:741:12)
 at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:285:19)
 at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:739:3)
```

Comment: You can put node or browser specific code inside of an if statement. e.g. `if(typeof require==='function') { /* .... */ }` or `if(typeof document==='object')`. You can also just check `if(require)`, but this can be problematic if you're working in strict mode because you can get errors if the variable hasn't been declared. `typeof` is safer in this respect.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. `document.getElementById` requires a DOM structure which is provided by a browser. Node.JS just doesn't have any document you can work in because it's entirely serverside. The first part may be doable within a browser but you'd have to drop the Node.JS specific calls and import some library that exposes similar functionality within a browser. With that said, you'd be grabbing a .jar file in a page and trying to run it which is not going to work on the vast majority of browsers.

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ and others. I believe what I need is simpler than I thought. I am not working on web page, I just need to cosume an API and I wanted to use the browser and the html file as the graphic interface. I know some coders do that but maybe there's an easier solution.